# Node js is showing same user data in all client applications

Tags: javascript, session, express, mean

i am new to Node Js i am trying to build a login page using node js but it is showing same data in all clients if i logged in one browser then the remaning browsers are directly showing user info who are logged first. in this(Below Images) i logged in Chrome but Opera also taken the username and password which are given in chrome

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code please?

Answer (score 0):

Disable your browsersync and it will work as expected